# Unable to access StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync() method

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 RT and I want to check if a particular folder/file exists or not in a `StorageFolder`. The documentation is defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync), but I'm surprised to find that I don't have access to that method. The method doesn't show up in the `Windows.Storage` namespace, and Visual Studio won't compile!

How do I resolve this? Does the method no longer exist? I think this is an issue with my app only; how do I work it out?

Comment: A method wouldn't show up in a namespace - it would show up when you try to call it *on a folder*. Please show a sample of the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. VisualStudio just doesn't resolve the method and even IntelliSense doesn't list the method on a StorageFolder type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that method isn't supported on Windows Phone 8.1, apparently.

The key is to look at the "Requirements (Windows 8.x and Windows Phone 8.x)" section at the bottom of the docs, which shows:

```
Minimum supported client    Windows 8.1
Minimum supported server    Windows Server 2012 R2
Minimum supported phone     None supported
```

Comment: Yeah, but kind of ambiguous. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227230) it says Min. supported phone as WP8 but [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync) it says that Windows Phones are not supported.

Comment: @Flipper: There's nothing ambiguous about that. The type `StorageFolder` is supported on WP8, but the *particular operation* `TryGetItemAsync` isn't. Just because a type exists on a particular platform doesn't mean that every single operation on it will be available on that platform.

Comment: Okay. Got it. So ideally I should check if a particular method of a library is supported on my platform or not.